# How do I turn off sneak toggle into holding the sneak button?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc

How do I turn off toggle sneak, because I want to hold the sneak but it just turns on and off whenever I press it?

I like bridging and with this toggle sneak, I can't speedbridge.

I am using version 1.8.9.

Comment: This sounds like a mod

Answer (score 1):

Normally in Minecraft, you'd be doing this through the Accessibility menu - the little human icon right of the "Quit Game" button in the main menu; change 'Sneak' from 'Toggle' to 'Hold'.

...but this is a new feature, present as of 1.15. The only way to get equivalent functionality in an antique like 1.8.9 is through operating system's accessibility - you probably turned Sticky Keys on - pressing Shift five times and then clicking 'OK' instead of 'Cancel' on the prompt that shows up. To turn it off, open "Ease of Access Keyboard Settings" in Windows, then disable Sticky Keys - and the 'shortcut key' when you're at it.

Comment: SF., I do not see any little human icons

Comment: I tried version 1.16.2 and there was a human icon, but the sneak button was turned to hold but it still isn't working.

Comment: Oh, the 1.16.2 works now but the 1.8.9 though. That's my main version that I play on.

Comment: @BaAnhTruong Did you check Sticky Keys?